# javascript: access to parent object in structure from the scope of the function in structure

Tags: javascript, function, scope, structure

Tell me how from the scope of the function (in structure) to access the elements of its parent (in structure)?

For example:

```
var mystruct = {
    element1: 10,
    element2: 'test',
    element3: {
        sub1: 'data',
        sub2: function(){
            return this;
        }
    },
};

var res = mystruct.element3.sub2();
```

result:

```
res = {sub1: 'data', sub2: f}
```

But how does the function mystruct.element3.sub2 access to the element mystruct.element1?

For example:

```
sub2: function(){
    return this.parent.element1;
}
```

result:

```
res = 10
```

Method:

```
sub2: function(){
    return mystruct.element1.sub1;
}
```

not suitable, because in the scope of the function I do not know about the mystruct

Comment: But the scope of that function **does** know about `mystruct`, at least in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to create element3, so you can save the parent object in a variable and then use it accordingly.

```
var mystruct = {
    element1: 10,
    element2: 'test',
    element3: (function () {
        // save the reference you want to access later
        var parent = this;
        // create and return the object that you want to assign to 'element3'
        return {
            sub1: 'data',
            sub2: function() {
                // use the saved reference
                return parent.element1;
            }
        }
    })()  // NOTE: immediately invoke the function to return the correct object
};
```

And afterwards you can use it as you wanted it:

```
mystruct.element3.sub2();  // will return 10
```

Or you can just use it's variable name:

```
sub2: function () {
    return mystruct.element1;
}
```

Comment: Because this looks so similar to Roby's answer, it's worth pointing out that using an IIFE provides saftey as it cannot be hijacked by doing something silly like `mystruct.element3.call(someOtherScope).sub2()`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to access the main object. One way would be to define 'element3' as a function so that you can create a closure for accessing 'mystruct'. Something like:

```
var mystruct = {
    element1: 10,
    element2: 'test',
    element3: function () {
        var parent = this;
        return {
            sub1: 'data',
            sub2: function(){
                return parent.element1;
            }
        }
    },
};
```

---

Which you can you use by:

```
mystruct.element3().sub2()
```

Gives:

```
10
```

Comment: Roby Rodriguez, i think, it's not a very convenient method, because additional objects (functions, variables) appear

Comment: well, if you really need to keep the original structure then perhaps you should use bind or apply on your function `var boundSub2 = mystruct.element3.sub2.bind(mystruct)` then, provided sub2 returns `this.element1`, when you call boundSub2() it will have mystruct's context and will return '10'

Comment: Or you could use an IIFE when you define the original object